# Computing $S_n (H)$ for $n \geq 1$ for the Gibbs`phenomenon.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

The Gibbs phenomenon is the fact that even when the Fourier series of a function $f$ converges at some point $t_{0}$ the convergence may be non-uniform in any neighborhood of $t_{0}$. We can find a sequence $t_{k}$ that converges to $t_{0}$ but with $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_{n}(t_{n}) \neq f(t_{0})$. This happens whenever $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $t_{0}$.

Let $$  H(t) = \begin{cases}
1 &  { 0<t< \pi}, \\
-1 & {-\pi< t < 0}
\end{cases}  $$ 
Compute $S_{n}(H)$ for $n \geq 1.$

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first to consider your (odd) function as coinciding with a square wave on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and, thus, have a corresponding Fourier series identical to this square wave, i.e.,

$$\tfrac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \tfrac{1}{2k+1}\sin{((2k+1)t)}$$

Then, see the very clear document (http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/gibbs-phenom.pdf)

Comment: what do you mean by saying "consider your (odd) function as coinciding with a square wave on $(-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: Do you agree that they concide ? The difference is that one has to consider the square wave (like repeated battlements in a castle) because we **need** periodic functions for applying Fourier series theory.

Comment: yes, I agreed :)